# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18). react native

Tags: react-native, debugging, visual-studio-code

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';

const App = () => <AppNavigator/>
export default App;
```

launch.json

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ]
    },

]
```

When i am trying to debug my app it showing the above error. I have already tried the following steps
Delete the node_modules directory
Delete the package-lock.json file
Run npm install
Run npm start

but the result is same. Why it is happening?

Comment: This often happens when you use a relative path and trying to import some files from the wrong directory.